# script that denies access to an ip after they have filled a form on my site

Tags: php, html

I have an existing php script written which checks if an ip has been written to a .dat, and redirects the user to in this case google if the ip is in the file. If not, it lets them continue on with signing up to my site.

The code below checks if the control is switched on. I placed it in the index.php

```
 if($One_time_access==1)
{
$fp = fopen("blacklist.dat", "a");
fputs($fp, "\r\n$ip\r\n");
fclose($fp);
}
```

Then the code below does all the work to figure out the ip, what to ban, etc

```
    <?php
class IpList {
    private $iplist = array();
    private $ipfile = "";
    public function __construct( $list ) {
        $contents = array();
        $this->ipfile = $list;
        $lines = $this->read( $list );
        foreach( $lines as $line ) {
            $line = trim( $line );
            # remove comment and blank lines
            if ( empty($line ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( $line[0] == '#' ) {
                continue;
            }
            # remove on line comments
            $temp = explode( "#", $line );
            $line = trim( $temp[0] );
            # create content array
            $contents[] = $this->normal($line);
        }       
        $this->iplist = $contents;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return implode(' ',$this->iplist);
    }

    public function is_inlist( $ip ) {
        $retval = false;        
        foreach( $this->iplist as $ipf ) {
            $retval = $this->ip_in_range( $ip, $ipf );
            if ($retval === true ) {
                $this->range = $ipf;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $retval;
    }

    /*
    ** public function that returns the ip list array
    */
    public function iplist() {
        return $this->iplist; 
    }

    /*
    */
    public function message() {
        return $this->range;
    }

    public function append( $ip, $comment ) {
        return file_put_contents( $this->ipfile, $ip, $comment ); 
    }

    public function listname() {
        return $this->ipfile;
    }

    /*
    ** private function that reads the file into array
    */
    private function read( $fname ) {
        try {
            $file = file( $fname, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES  );
        }
        catch( Exception $e ) {
            throw new Exception( $fname.': '.$e->getmessage() . '\n');
        }
        return $file;
    }

    private function ip_in_range( $ip, $range ) {

        // return ip_in_range( $ip, $range );

        if ( strpos($range, '/') !== false ) {
            // IP/NETMASK format
            list( $range, $netmask ) = explode( '/', $range, 2 );
            if ( strpos( $netmask, '.' ) !== false ) {
                // 255.255.255.0 format w/ wildcards
                $netmask = str_replace('*', '0', $netmask );
                $dnetmask = ip2long( $netmask );
                return ((ip2long( $ip ) & $dnetmask) == (ip2long($range) & $dnetmask ));
            }
            else {
                // IP/CIDR format
                // insure $range format 0.0.0.0
                $r = explode( '.', $range );
                while( count( $r ) < 4 ) {
                    $r[] = '0';
                }
                for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                    $r[$i] = empty($r[$i]) ? '0': $r[$i];
                }
                $range = implode( '.', $r );
                // build netmask
                $dnetmask = ~(pow( 2, ( 32 - $netmask)) - 1);
                return ((ip2long($ip) & $dnetmask)==(ip2long($range) & $dnetmask));
            }
        }
        else {
            if ( strpos( $range, '*' ) !== false ) {
                // 255.255.*.* format
                $low = str_replace( '*', '0', $range );
                $high = str_replace( '*', '255', $range );
                $range = $low.'-'.$high;
            }
            if ( strpos( $range, '-') !== false ) {
                // 128.255.255.0-128.255.255.255 format
                list( $low, $high ) = explode( '-', $range, 2 );

                $dlow  = $this->toLongs( $low );
                $dhigh = $this->toLongs( $high );
                $dip   = $this->toLongs( $ip );
                return (($this->compare($dip,$dlow) != -1) && ($this->compare($dip,$dhigh) != 1)); 
            }
        }
        return ( $ip == $range );
    }
    private function normal( $range ) {
        if ( strpbrk( "*-/", $range ) === False ) {
            $range .= "/32";
        }
        return str_replace( ' ', '', $range );
    }
    private function toLongs( $ip ) {
        # $Ip = $this->expand();
        # $Parts = explode(':', $Ip);
        $Parts = explode('.', $ip );
        $Ip = array('', '');
        # for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
            $Ip[0] .= str_pad(base_convert($Parts[$i], 16, 2), 16, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        # for ($i = 4; $i < 8; $i++) { 
        for ($i = 2; $i < 4; $i++) { 
            $Ip[1] .= str_pad(base_convert($Parts[$i], 16, 2), 16, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        return array(base_convert($Ip[0], 2, 10), base_convert($Ip[1], 2, 10));
    }

    private function compare( $ipdec1, $ipdec2 ) {
        if( $ipdec1[0] < $ipdec2[0] ) {
            return -1;
        }
        elseif ( $ipdec1[0] > $ipdec2[0] ) {
            return 1;
        }
        elseif ( $ipdec1[1] < $ipdec2[1] ) {
            return -1;
        }
        elseif ( $ipdec1[1] > $ipdec2[1] ) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
class IpBlockList {

    private $statusid = array( 'negative' => -1, 'neutral' => 0, 'positive' => 1 );

    private $whitelist = array();
    private $blacklist = array();
    private $message   = NULL;
    private $status    = NULL;

    public function __construct( 
        $whitelistfile = 'assets/includes/whitelist.dat', 
        $blacklistfile = 'assets/includes/blacklist.dat' ) {
        $this->whitelistfile = $whitelistfile;
        $this->blacklistfile = $blacklistfile;

        $this->whitelist = new IpList( $whitelistfile );
        $this->blacklist = new IpList( $blacklistfile );
    }

    public  function    __destruct() { 
    }

    public function ipPass( $ip ) {
        $retval = False;

        if ( !filter_var( $ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 ) ) {
            throw new Exception( 'Requires valid IPv4 address' );
        }

        if ( $this->whitelist->is_inlist( $ip ) ) {
            // Ip is white listed, so it passes
            $retval = True;
            $this->message = $ip . " is whitelisted by ".$this->whitelist->message().".";
            $this->status = $this->statusid['positive'];
        }
        else if ( $this->blacklist->is_inlist( $ip ) ) {
            $retval = False;
            $this->message = $ip . " is blacklisted by ".$this->blacklist->message().".";
            $this->status = $this->statusid['negative'];
        }
        else {
            $retval = True;
            $this->message = $ip . " is unlisted.";
            $this->status = $this->statusid['neutral'];
        }
        return $retval;
    }

    public function message() {
        return $this->message;
    }

         public function status() {
             return $this->status;
         }

    public function append( $type, $ip, $comment = "" ) {
        if ($type == 'WHITELIST' ) {
            $retval = $this->whitelistfile->append( $ip, $comment );
        }
        elseif( $type == 'BLACKLIST' ) {
            $retval = $this->blacklistfile->append( $ip, $comment );
        }
        else {
            $retval = false;
        }
    }

    public function filename( $type, $ip, $comment = "" ) {
        if ($type == 'WHITELIST' ) {
            $retval = $this->whitelistfile->filename( $ip, $comment );
        }
        elseif( $type == 'BLACKLIST' ) {
            $retval = $this->blacklistfile->filename( $ip, $comment );
        }
        else {
            $retval = false;
        }
    }
}
$ips = array(   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                 );
$checklist = new IpBlockList( );
foreach ($ips as $ip ) {
$result = $checklist->ipPass( $ip );
    if ( $result ) {
        // Continue with page
    }
    else {
        header("Location: https://www.google.co.uk/");
        die();
    }   
}
?>
```

I want to know:
1. can i write the ips to a text file instead of .dat?
2. is there an easier way to do this?/shorter script?

All help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Don't use a file at all - use a database. That would be simpler, right?

Comment: Don't do that unless you want your domain to be blacklisted by Google.  They actively check for that now.

Comment: Buddy,You are making it too hard on yourself..! Just simply use a database as @EatPeanutButter suggested..!

Comment: Looking at the code, I'm not sure it would be much simpler to use a DB.